# NFC reading in Activity goes to sleep?

Tags: android, nfc

I have an application which has to be able to read NFC tags on the main screen continouosly.
Sometimes it can read very well from 2-3 cm distance, sometimes nothing happens for 5-10 seconds, even if I touch the card multiple times to the built-in reader.

I think maybe the NFC reader goes into sleep mode after a while, or I have no idea what causes that.

Is there any way to ensure continouos reading (at least when the device is plugged-in)?

in `onCreate()`:

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, 
    (new Intent(this, this.getClass())).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP), 0);
```

in `onResume()`:

```
        NfcAdapter nfcAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);
        if ( nfcAdapter != null ) {
            if ( !nfcAdapter.isEnabled() ) {
                this.showNFCSettings();
            }
            nfcAdapter.enableForegroundDispatch(this, this.pendingIntent, null, null);
        }
```

Comment: Which of the 2 modes of reading NFC cards are you using? `enableForegroundDispatch` or `enableReaderMode`

Comment: I edited the question.  :)
I'm using `enableForegroundDispatch `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `enableForegroundDispatch` method the rough order of operation is:-

1) When a card comes in to range your Application gets paused and the Android OS "App" starts running

2) The Android OS "App" starts reading the card to determine the type and if the card contains NDEF data it will read all the data (this could take a short while depending on the card and data). This could happen a number of times if the card goes in and out of range while it is trying to read.

3) The Android OS "App" plays a sound and inserts an Intent in to your App's message queue.

4) Your App is resumed and it will start processing it's message queue and when it gets to the message with the Intent in it, it will fire the `newIntent` method.

So there are areas that can introduce delays in to this process, if your app optionally does other stuff in `onPause` and `onResume` then this could delay the process and other items in the App's message queue could delay the `Intent` being processed.

The key to understanding is there NDEF data on the card and when it is delayed is the sound from the OS also delayed or is it a delay between the sound and your App `onNewIntent` running?

I would not use `enableForegroundDispatch` to handle cards if you can but use `enableReaderMode` as `enableForegroundDispatch` is not as reliable, especially when writing to cards.

It has also been noted that that there is a BUG in some Broadcom NFC controllers that means it can spend too much time check to see if the card is in range for reading to actually happen. With `enableReaderMode` you can control this polling.

It has also been noted https://stackoverflow.com/a/50081331/2373819 that `enableForegroundDispatch` has heavy power optimisation that could be failing to power the card until it is closer in range or one of the less frequent long polling events happen. Again `enableReaderMode` seems to be better here and more likely to power the card sooner (at the cost of using more power)

Comment: Thanks, it's much better with `enableReaderMode` instead of `enableForegroundDispatch`, and the reading range improved a lot...  :)

Answer (score 0):

if the tag is discoverd and you don't use it for reading or writing for 1 minute, the nfc will automatically turns off, and you should to switch nfc off/on or screen off/on .
if you keep sending and commands to tag and keep receiving something back, the interface will stay on.